# Philosophical Positions on the Purpose and Qualities of Art

Tags: aesthetics, art, music

What are some philosophical stances on art and its purpose? I know this is a broad question, but any sources or thoughts would be great.

I am particularly interested in music.

Comment: This book introduces Vienna and many important characters connected with it at a certain important time. Title: Schoenberg, Berg, and Webern : a companion to the second Viennese school, Author: Simms, Bryan R. , Publisher:Greenwood Press,Pub date:c1999.

Comment: A classic, Adorno, Brecht et. al.  https://www.versobooks.com/books/127-aesthetics-and-politics  Going back: Plato-Republic-Artists; Forward:  Wagner-Nietzsche (Wagner didn't need any help, so influence was from Wagner to Nietzsche, while it lasted).  Post WWI "feel" perhaps listen to Berg's Wozzeck. Info: https://muse.jhu.edu/article/546852/summary

Comment: I found this article tonight regarding Henri Bergson and possible influence on Schoenberg. http://www.mtosmt.org/issues/mto.15.21.4/mto.15.21.4.salley.html

Comment: Art does not have a single purpose. Music can make you dance, but painting won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adorno might be interesting to you, but consider looking at certain composers who also “write” — Cage and Xenakis come to mind.

Attali’s *Noise: The Political Economy of Music* is also highly recommended in this vein.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a list of things that ***good music*** communicates.  I'll repeat it here:

Beauty

Emotion (or drama)

Imitation (of nature)

Bigness (or awe)

Virtuosity (of the performer)

Practical social functions (like dance or work songs)

Unifying social functions (like anthems)

Memory (or recognition)